# Is there a way to specify java annotations in antlr grammar files?

Tags: java, antlr

I'm looking for  a way to include a few additional strings in output .java files generated from antlr. Is there a comprehensive listing of available directives? For example, given parser output like this:

```
package com.foo.bar; //<-- this can be generated with @header { .... }
//antlr generated
import org.antlr.runtime.*; 
...

//<-- is there a way to generate anything here?
public class MyParser {

    //<--- or here?
    public void f1(){ ... }

}
```

Is there a way to generate strings that appear after the import statements (e.g. class-level annotations) or possibly method annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot do this. The [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Definitive-ANTLR-Reference-Domain-Specific-Programmers/dp/0978739256/) doesn't mention anything. Maybe you can ask at the [mail list](http://www.antlr.org/mailman/listinfo/antlr-interest): antlr-interest@antlr.org

Comment: Correct: the only way to do this is by editing the code-generator template files for the Java target in this case (`.stg`, if I'm not mistaken).